# How to use my laptop as a loudspeaker?

Tags: audio, speakers, microphone

As the title mentions, I want to use my laptop as a loud speaker. I would talk using my mic connected to the laptop and the sound should come from the speakers.

I have Windows7 home edition on my new laptop.

I prefer built-in feature but third-party software for this is also welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click the sound icon in the notification area, click `Recording devices`.

   [[image: Screenshot of sounds context menu]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2OPp.png)
2. Open the properties of the appropriate device - it might be a built-in mic, or a line-in.
3. Go to the `Listen` tab.
4. Check `Listen to this device`.

   [[image: Screenshot of Listen tab]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6kya.png)
5. Click `OK` or `Apply`.

Comment: I would add Step 5. Click "Apply." Mine wouldn't work until I did that but then viola!